# How to reset the state of a screen that was opened by the drawer navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a route configuration that first opens a login screen, and after the user logs in, he is redirected to the home screen, with the following configuration.

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
const navigation = useNavigation();

export function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Navigator>
      <Screen name="Login" component={Login}/>
      <Screen name="HomeRoutes" component={HomeRoutes}/>
    </Navigator>
  );
}
```

The navigation that the user is redirected after login has been implemented using the drawer navigator.

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
const { Navigator, Screen } = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function HomeRoutes() {
  return (
    <Navigator>
      <Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
      <Screen name="InfoUser" component={InfoUser}/>
    </Navigator >
  );
}
```

When the user is at the "Home" screen and he navigates to the "InfoUser" screen for the first time, a useEffect is performed requesting data from the server. However, if the user goes back to the home screen and then navigates back to the "InfoUser" screen, this useEffect is not executed again, the screen remains in the same state that the user left the first time he navigated to it. I need that every time he enters this screen, this useEffect request is executed. For navigation I'm using `navigation.navigate('InfoUser')`. What should I do differently to get this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Use `useFocus` instead of useEffect.